# Android Manifest implementation issues

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest, splash-screen

I have never fully understood the manifest or how to add items to it. I have the manifest here that is working but I want to change something and I do not know what to change. Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.magicbuddy.gamble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.welcomeSplash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Player"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Popup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_popup" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have 2 new classes I have written. One is called Player.class and the other is called WelcomeSplash.class. Currently, as the manifest shows, that my splash screen loads and works and then the timer on the splash screen auto loads the next screen, the dashboard.class. Instead I want it to load one of my new classes, the WelcomeSplash.class. I do not know how to get my two new classes properly added into the manifest.

```
     startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, welcomeSplash.class));
```

I replaced WelcomeSplash with another one of my classes, Dashboard, and it does not force close, it loads and runs just fine.

Comment: use the intent defined in my answer

Comment: "I replaced WelcomeSplash with another one of my classes" if you use "Splash" you will have no problems cause its has an intent-filter "launcher", but thats not the correct way to use the intent.

Answer (score 3):

Just as per your code, i make the changes and post the codehere. check and Use in `Manifest`..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.magicbuddy.gamble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"            />
        </intent-filter>



    <activity
        android:name=".gamble.Dashboard" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Player" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Popup" >
    </activity>
 <activity android:name=".WelcomeSplash" >
        </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

No need to write  `<intent-filter>` again. Thnk you :)

Comment: I think he tried with <activity android:name=".welcomeSplash" > too.

Comment: Sry Its <activity android:name=".WelcomeSplash" > as a activity name starts in caps.

Answer (score 1):

For every new activity you create you need to add the activity block to the manifest in the application section.

To add your new WelcomeSplash class, add the line:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.WelcomeSplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

between the tags

```
<application></application>
```

Once the class is in there your splash class should start the intent with WelcomeSplash.class

Comment: I added copy and paste exactly what you posted but the app force closes when the WelcomeSplash class gets called. The logcat says there is no activty to handle intent (com.XXXX.WelcomeSplash)

Comment: Could you post your startActivity() method call from your Splash class?

Comment: added the code, just a note though that it was origionally set up to be used with the Dashboard class, and when I put the dashboard.this back it does not force close anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As dgg says just add the activities  into your `Manifest.xml`

```
    <application>
...
...
...
        <activity
            android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Player"
            android:label="Player" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.welcomeSplash"
            android:label="WelcomeSplash" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

if you have the exception "`there is no activty to handle intent (com.XXXX.WelcomeSplash)` here:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.magicbuddy.gamble.welcomeSplash");
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

you must use:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(this, welcomeSplash.class); 
startActivity(startMain);
```

read more about : **[Android Build an Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)**

Here´s a question for you, whats the real name of your class,  "`WelcomeSplash`" or "`welcomeSplash`", put the correct name on your `Manifest.xml` and in your `Intent`! :)

According to Java Standars, Class Names should be in `CamelCase`, so use "`WelcomeSplash`".

Comment: it is still force closing with the same message that there is no activity to handle the intent

Comment: I can not figure out what the problem is to save my life. Do I not need any intent filters in the manifest for anything?

Comment: after adding the entries to the manifest like you posted, do they need intent filters or anything else? because the way you mentioned is not working.

Comment: No intent filters are not required, just be sure that are really activities, "public class WelcomeSplash extends Activity", be patient :)

Comment: Sorry for being jumpy, I really do appreciate your help so far. I do have the WelcomeSplash extends Activity at the top. While playing around in the manifest I removed the intent filters from the dashboard.class which is what is autoloading where I want the WelcomeSplash to run. When I removed the intent filters there it also force closed. When I put the intent filters back and moved them under the WelcomeSplash it still force closed. When i put the intent filters back under the Dashboard class the app will run sucessfully

Comment: I edited the manifest and the way I am trying to load the welcomeSplash. It still force closes with a Nullpointexception now.

Comment: just check the name of your class "WelcomeSplash" or "welcomeSplash", put the correct name on your Manifest.xml and in your Intent! :)